# List positioning for keyframe animation

Tags: html, css

I am trying arround with keyframe animations and wrote this piece for a nice animation of `li` elements:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rZGgLg
HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
$total-items: 5;

body {
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
}

ul {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: -150px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

// Set delay per list item
@for $i from 1 through $total-items {
  li:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: 1s * $i;
  }
}

// Keyframe animation
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 100px;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Now I am struggeling to integrate this into the following piece:

```css
.half-width>.half-width-content {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.half-width>.half-width-content>.list-div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="half-width">
  <div class="half-width-content">
    <div class="list-div">
      <ul class="items-list" id="list">
        <li>Entry A</li>
        <li>Entry B</li>
        <li>Entry C</li>
        <li>Entry D</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I position the `ul` in the `list-div` to absolute, they have almost no width.

Can someone help me here, so the `li` elements are animated the same way as in the simple example above?

Comment: if you give an element `position: absolute;` you have to define `width`, it's nothing new. what you want actually.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 'simple example' your `ul` element has a width of 300 pixels. When you apply the same width to the new code, it works as expected.

In my code, I used a flexbox to horizontally center the list. More information on flexbox can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
}

.list-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 300px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  animation: fadeIn 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 100px;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="half-width">
  <div class="half-width-content">
    <div class="list-div">
      <ul class="items-list" id="list">
        <li>Entry A</li>
        <li>Entry B</li>
        <li>Entry C</li>
        <li>Entry D</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```